# How do I do the equivalent of setTimeout + clearTimeout in Dart?

Tags: dart, settimeout, dart-async

I'm porting some JavaScript to Dart. I have code that uses `window.setTimeout` to run a callback after a period of time. In some situations, that callback gets canceled via `window.clearTimeout`.

What is the equivalent of this in Dart? I can use `new Future.delayed` to replace `setTimeout`, but I can't see a way to cancel this. Nor can I find away to call `clearTimeout` from Dart.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the [Timer class](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:async.Timer)

```dart
import 'dart:async';

var timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => print('done'));

timer.cancel();
```

Comment: Cool; will try this. Is `Timer` just a wrapper around a `Future` that's internally setting a `bool` when canceled?

Comment: As far as I know this is not how it is. `Future.delayed` uses a `Timer` but otherwise I think they are not related (not sure though).

Comment: Yes use Time for something that can be cancelled. Future.delayed uses a Timer in the background, not vice versa. You can see the implementation here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/sdk/lib/async/future.dart#224

Comment: The Dart source code is now available on GitHub. The link to the `Future.delayed` factory is available here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/async/future.dart

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mimic the JavaScript API:

```
import 'dart:async';

Timer setTimeout(callback, [int duration = 1000]) {
  return Timer(Duration(milliseconds: duration), callback);
}

void clearTimeout(Timer t) {
  t.cancel();
}
```